# Checking whether there is a certain value for a given id of one data frame in another

Tags: r, string, dataframe, compare

I have two data.frames "a" and "b".

```
str(a)
'data.frame':   1597 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id : int  ...
 $ age: num  ...

> str(b)
'data.frame':   12877 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id      : int  ...
 $ code    : chr  ...
```

While "id" is unique in "a" it is not in "b". To be more precisely, there is a 1:n relation between "a" and "b". I want to check whether there is a certain code in "b" for "a$id". How can I do this?

I think, that I need something like:

```
a$code.I25 <- ifelse(<if there is a$id in b$id and for b$id an entry with "I25" for b$code>, 1, 0)
```

Unfortunately it is a little bit more complicated. The values of "b$code" are not only like "I25" but rather like "I25.11" or "I25.12". However, I just want to compare "I25" and want to get a true for both, "I25.11" and "I25.12". Is this possible?

Comment: does b$code only have that pattern? i.e I25.11, I25.12? You could create a new variable in data.frame b by using regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#create a dummy data.frame for a 
foo.a <- data.frame(id = 1:20,age = rnorm(20,25))
foo.b <-data.frame(id = 1:40,
code = as.character(paste(c("I25","I27"),1:20,sep = ".")))
#replicate it randomly
set.seed(357)
foo.b <-foo.b[sample(nrow(foo.b),75, replace = T),]
#check for matches
id.match <-which(foo.b$id %in% foo.a$id)
#get matching rows
foo.b[grep("I25",foo.b$code[id.match]),]
```

Comment: Thanks to you all; The last answer from infominer works fine so far. Only one question is left. For example, there a more than one subcode for "I25" like "I25.1", "I25.2" and so on. But I just want to know whether there is at least on of these subcodes for a given id and in that case, I need the value "1" in "foo.a$i25", otherwise "0". What would the easiest way and shortest (code line- wise) to to this?

Comment: How about accepting my answer then? As for your question, use `ifelse` like you did in your post.  I will leave the implementation as an exercise!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
id_a = c(1, 2, 3, 23, 19, 11:13, 4, 6)
id_b = c(1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 11:13, 3, 3)
code_b = c(rep("I25", 4), rep("I26", 5), "I25")

a = data.frame(id = id_a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a
#    id
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3   3
# 4  23
# 5  19
# 6  11
# 7  12
# 8  13
# 9   4
# 10  6

b = data.frame(id = id_b, code = code_b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

b
#    id code
# 1   1  I25
# 2   2  I25
# 3   2  I25
# 4   5  I25
# 5   8  I26
# 6  11  I26
# 7  12  I26
# 8  13  I26
# 9   3  I26
# 10  3  I25

index = which(b$id %in% a$id)

b[index[which(b[index,]$code %in% "I25")],]

# id code
# 1   1  I25
# 2   2  I25
# 3   2  I25
# 10  3  I25

b[index[which(b[index,]$code %in% c("I25", "I26"))],]

#    id code
# 1   1  I25
# 2   2  I25
# 3   2  I25
# 6  11  I26
# 7  12  I26
# 8  13  I26
# 9   3  I26
# 10  3  I25
```

#True | False

```
b$TF = rep(NA, nrow(b))

b$TF[index[which(b[index,]$code %in% c("I25", "I26"))]] <- 1

b$TF[-(index[which(b[index,]$code %in% c("I25", "I26"))])] <- 0

b
#    id code TF
# 1   1  I25  1
# 2   2  I25  1
# 3   2  I25  1
# 4   5  I25  0
# 5   8  I26  0
# 6  11  I26  1
# 7  12  I26  1
# 8  13  I26  1
# 9   3  I26  1
# 10  3  I25  1
```

Comment: saw that, OP has "I25.11" and "I25.12"  and not just I25

Comment: concatenate the strings for matching as in b[which(b$code %in% c("I25.11", "I25.12")),]  should work